# response.setContentType() getting reset in Java Filter

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I'm trying to set the content type of my gzipped files to be of the correct mime type, rather than application/gzip, in a filter. Here's some of my code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,  FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String reqUrl = request.getRequestURI();
    if (reqUrl.endsWith(gzExt))
    {
        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        response.setContentType("text/javascript");

        System.out.println("Set header " +reqUrl +", " + response.getContentType() );

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        System.out.println("Header now: " + reqUrl + ", " + response.getContentType() );
        return;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Set header /test.js.gz, text/javascript
Header now: /test.js.gz, application/x-gzip
```

In the browser, I see that the `content-encoding` is correctly set to `gzip`, but the `content-type` remains at `application/x-gzip`. It seems that `filterChain.doFilter()` is resetting the content type.

Any idea how to permanently reset the content type?

I don't have any other filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195207/49153):

```
private class ForcableContentTypeWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
    public ForcableContentTypeWrapper(HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentType(String type)
    {
    }
    public void forceContentType(String type)
    {
        super.setContentType(type);
    }
}
```

Then changed my above code to:

```
    if (reqUrl.endsWith(gzExt))
    {
        ForcableContentTypeWrapper newResponse = new ForcableContentTypeWrapper(response);
        newResponse.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        newResponse.forceContentType("text/javascript");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, newResponse);
        return;
    }
```

Its not a pretty workaround, but it works.

Comment: let me know which answer deserves the bounty ;)

Comment: @Omar Its upto you, in my specific case, I needed to specify the mime type at runtime, and I didn't want to have to run this filter last. So my solution worked for me, but for others, another solution may be better.

Comment: @Omar However Alex's answer won't work because even if you moved it to the last filter, the container's default servlet will run after the filter and will reset the content type (at least in case of Tomcat)

Comment: BalusC's answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Omar In my specific case, no, because I was serving different types of files, e.g css, javascript, images. So the mime type had to be specified at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should **always**  call  (or have very good reason not to do so)

```
 filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

or filters declared after this one will not be called.

Next,  move call filterChain.doFilter() to the top of method, set your headers after  and declare your filter mapping as last in web.xml.
And this will work as expected.