# Tomcat 8.5 response.getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, printwriter, tomcat8.5

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.23 in production with Servlets (with Spring autowiring capabilities if relevant)
`response.getWriter()` return `null` in production

It happens also when calling `chain.doFilter(req, res);` in custom filter:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
  public void destroy() {}
}
```

Exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:591)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:194)
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.getBody(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:89)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
```

I tried adding [HttpServletResponseWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846178/response-setcontenttype-getting-reset-in-java-filter) but it didn't worked

Comment: The `HttpServletResponse` as implemented in tomcat cannot return null. There are two cases: 1. `getOutputStream()` was called -> it will throw `IllegalStateException`, 2. the inner writer is null: it will create a new `CoyoteWriter`. Must probably some of the filters are wrapping the response object and do not handle some case correctly. Just step through the filter chain with a debugger. Definitely not a tomcat issue.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev the problem it happens only few times, and currently can't be reproduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter code looks OK, the problem is elsewhere. A comment already mentioned that `getWriter()` cannot return `null`. Have a look at the code where this seems to occur. Chances are that the code tries to assign the writer to a variable, but catches and ignores that exception. After the point where the exception gets ignored, somebody tries to use the variable, but it contains `null` because the assignment didn't take place.

One common case where these "already called" errors may happen is in error handling. A servlet started to send a response, therefore called `getWriter()`. Then it runs into an error, and the error handling tries to write an error response, therefore calls `getWriter()` again. You cannot reproduce the problem because that error situation occurs randomly.

Comment: But the problem isn't in the filter, afaict.

Comment: But filter executes before servlet

Comment: Your filter executes - without a problem - then calls the servlet. The servlet runs into a problem. Your filter doesn't even call `getWriter()`, so how could the problem of `getWriter()` returning `null` materialize in your filter?